# GENTOO: disadvantages to using genkernel all?

Tags: linux, gentoo, linux-kernel

I'm wondering, what are the disadvantages to using `genkernel` when I'm compiling a kernel in gentoo? Is it perfectly ok to use `genkernel all` in pretty much any situation and skip this difficult/arduous part of the installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no disadvantages as far as I am aware of, other than the project lacking manpower; so, if you go for really specialized situations with the kernel, you might come across a bug or two.

Yes, you can use `genkernel` just fine for a lot of situations. You can find some basic configuration options in `/etc/genkernel.conf` if you need them.